# Confusing lambda expression in python

Tags: python, lambda

I a little bit confused about this one liner

```
tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)
```

How it is possible? (lambda should return default dict but how we can put first arg as tree?)

Comment: functions are evaluated when they're called, so you can put anything on the right hand side that you want.  `tree = lambda: bananarama` is valid, up until you call it and the lookup on `bananarama` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambdas delay evaluation of their contents until they are called, so when `tree()` is called and `defaultdict(tree)` is evaluated, `tree` will be well defined, and thus not cause any issues. A more explicit example:

```
>>> foo = lambda: bar
>>> foo()
NameError: global name 'bar' is not defined
>>> bar = 5
>>> foo()
5
```

As for what this particular lambda does: The first argument to `defaultdict` is a factory method used when a key is missing(see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) for details). So the one-liner

```
tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)
```

defines a dictionary that by default contains other dictionaries. I.e. a tree.

For example:

```
my_tree = tree()
```

creates a new tree, and the following two lines do the same thing:

```
my_tree["foo"]
my_tree["foo"] = defaultdict(tree)
```

Namely creating a new subtree named "foo". New elements can thus be added deep into the tree without creating each subtree manually. For example:

```
root = tree()
root["foo"]["bar"]["baz"] = False
```